# Will the end address of the vector change if we erase some elements from the vector because in vector, memory is allotted sequentially (same as array)

Tags: c++, vector, erase

If I erase vector elements using the erase() function in c++, will the address of the end element also shift since the memory in vector is allotted sequentially?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you are correct.

More formally, all *iterators* and *references* at or after the first point of the erase, including the `end()` iterator, are invalidated.

In other words the addresses of the elements prior to the point of the erase stay the same, but not those after.

Comment: so the address of elements after the point of erasure shifts towards v.begin() by one each time I erase an element?

Comment: @MONISMUSHTAQUE: Yes that's correct, that's a corollary of how `std::vector` is required to operate.